# Get a pointer instead of a reference from a boost::ptr_vector

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, ptr-vector

I recently found the boost ptr_vector useful to manage my collection of heap-allocated objects. The pointer collection library is very nice, but unfortunately, I'm being held up by one thing.

Another part of my code needs to explicitly hold a pointer to one of my objects in the ptr_vector (for specific reasons it cannot be a reference). However, when you access an object in a ptr_vector, you get a reference, T& (even though you used ptr_vector.push_back(T *)

Is there anyway I can get a plain pointer out of a boost::ptr_vector?

Comment: Can you explain why it must be a pointer? Maybe there is an alternative.

Comment: Can you also explain what you mean by *hold*: does it imply ownership ? Or merely to access the pointed value ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes,

```
boost::ptr_vector<int> v;
v.push_back(new int());
int* ptr = &v[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

Same way you do from a regular vector: `&myvec[index]`. Of course you're on your own ensuring that the pointer is not used after the object is no longer there. If this becomes difficult then you can consider switching to a `vector<shared_ptr<T> >` rather than a `ptr_vector<T>`.